# How to remove a string from a string

Tags: c#

I am adding a string (a) to another string (b) before I store it in DB, when I retrieve the value from DB, I want to remove the string(b) from string (a). string (b) is a constant. How can I do it

```
string a= "text1";
string b="text2";
string c = a+b;
```

I want to remove b from c after I retrive it from db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = c.Replace(b, "");
```

Would be a simple way to do so.

Comment: May lead to problems if `a` can contain `b` before appending `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than do any of that, create a computed column in the DB that has the extra text.

Less storage; less code.

Comment: Or if he's using a an ORM, maybe some kind of "on adding" and "on updating" field interceptor.

Answer (score 2):

Try `String.Replace` - MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As @SvenS has pointed in @Khaled Nassar answer, using `String.Replace` won't work "as is" in your situation.

One acceptable solution may @Mitch's one, but if you don't have that access to modify your database, maybe there's another solution in pure C#:

```
int indexOfB = c.LastIndexOf(b);
string cWithoutB = c;

if(indexOfB >= 0)
{
     c.Substring(0, indexOfB);
}
```

This prevents replacing more than once the same string as **b**, because who knows if some user save the same text as **b** and logic shouldn't be removing it if it's not the one predefined by your application.